# How create DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from simple DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I create user control, editing, showing range DataGridView.

My user control takes DataTable

```
public static DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    var myDataTable = new DataTable();

    DataColumn myDataColumn;

    myDataColumn = new DataColumn
    {
        DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
        ColumnName = "id",
        ReadOnly = true
    };
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

    myDataColumn = new DataColumn
    {
        DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"),
        ColumnName = "citys"
    };
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);
    return myDataTable;
}
```

I set myDataTables to DataSource and all worked.

but I need to create column citys DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn oCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
oCol.Name = "cities";
oCol.DataSource = //your DataSource
myDataGridView.Columns.Add(oCol);
```

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
        DataTable table = CreateDataTable();
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
        }
        //there is you code too here.
```